# Overlay text on each gridview cell

Tags: android, overlay, android-gridview

It sounds simple enough, yet I am unable to figure out a method.

I have a `gridview`, and I want to overlay a text on top of it - on its top right corner with some padding from the edges.

Some options I considered -

1. `layer-list` - can't use this as it has no support for text, but only for images (or so I found out, correct me if I am wrong)
2. `ViewOverlay`/`ViewGroupOverlay` - can't be used in APIs less than 18.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

And by the way, each cell has to be overlayed with a different text. And sometimes, I may need to disable the overlay *for a particular cell*.

Comment: add one TextView to your GridView cell (parent of cell must RelativeLayout or FrameLayout) and disable/enable from getView() of your Adapter

Comment: Not an option. The grid cells are each having an image and I want some part of the overlayed text to overlap with the image in the cell.

Comment: the option i have suggested is definitely useful for your purpose. try it once and see

Comment: No its not. Please read carefully what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a different layout and then inflate over your gridview layout.

Comment: how exactly? and how for each cell?

Comment: You have to use custom adapter for all cells.